# .env file loads cached values

Tags: vue.js, webpack, environment-variables, production-environment

I am using `VUE CLI 3`, here I have created custom `.env` file, while development and when I try to access from `.env` file like this,

in `.env` file,

`VUE_APP_MAIL_ID=test@gmail.com`,

In one of the components file,

`process.enc.VUE_APP_MAIL_ID`, I get the value, and if at all I want to change the mail id in the development I can run

`npm cache clear --force` and now I get the updated value.

But if I deployed on the server and I created `.env` file, it loads correctly, there would be cases that we want to change the mail id in the in server itself in that case it loads the older data not with new data.

How can we fix that ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you include a variable in the Webpack bundle, it won't store the reference of the variable but the value of the variable. I solved the problem by discluding the environmental variables from the bundle and including them as a plain JS/JSON file at the top of my index.html. So if you edit the JSON or the JS on the server, it should work.